# How to fix not working keybind in WebStorm IDE

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide, key-bindings

I generally have a bunch of custom keybinds for WebStorm, but this one particularly does not work - `Select opened file`. I've bound it with different key combinations (see screenshots below), and also I've verified that it does not conflict with any MacOS keybinds (although even the ones that conflict actually do work).

Also when I hover the actual UI button, it shows different keybind for it (which also does not work).

So, essentially, I have to always click the UI button with the mouse. I'd like to be able to do so with the keybind. I'm not even sure how to troubleshoot this...

Does anyone else using WebStorm have this keybind working properly?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known usability issue, [IDEA-271054](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-271054). The actual action you need assigning a shortcut to is **Other | Select File in Project View**:

[image]

Comment: Interesting. That solved it, thanks!